# Boyer-Moore with Don't Cares

Tags: algorithms, search-algorithms, strings

I have been doing a lot of research into pattern matching algorithms. 
For some background I am searching a long binary alphabet text consisting of considerably more 0s than 1s. The individual patterns I am searching for are of the form 11111, 1*1*1*1*1, 1**1**1**1**1**1, etc, where * is the Don't Care symbol (so either 1 or 0). I think that Boyer-Moore would be quite effective, however I understand that Boyer-Moore string matching can't be modified to work with Don't Care symbols. Is there something with this ability and similar performance?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to search for anything that matches $\cup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} 1(0|1)^k 1 (0|1)^k 1 (0|1)^k  (0|1)^k$?  What algorithms have you considered?

Comment: Sort of. I don't necessarily want to find everything of that pattern, just single instances where k >= 0. I've looked at things like the shift-and algorithm, Aho-Corasick and variations, naive searching and regexes. There were others, but they weren't close to what I want.

Comment: What do you mean by "single instances"?  Let me ask it another way.  What is the input to the algorithm?  Is the input only the string, and the output is at least one match (if there exists a match for any value of $k$) or else the output "no match exists"?  Or is the input a string and a set of values of $k$ (a set of patterns of the form you listed)?  If the set of values of $k$ is given as input, that makes the problem a bit different.

Comment: No, the input would be a single input string with some don't cares and the output would be matches on the text. I just stated the form of the strings which might be checked in case that would help find a good algorithm.

Comment: what about substring? do we provide k? how long will the pattern be? etc.

Comment: James, that doesn't make any sense to me.   I think you need to edit the question to specify the problem much more clearly, and give an example input and output. I could understand if the input was a string $S$ and a pattern $P$ (where $P$ has don't-cares and is of the form you listed).  I could understand if the input was a string $S$ (which is matched against the pattern I gave in my first comment; the pattern doesn't vary), but then the input shouldn't have any don't-cares.  I don't see how you could have a single input string that does contain don't-cares.  Try providing an example?